# Prove that $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ is not prime if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Prove that  $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ is not prime.

We can rewrite $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ as $$\dfrac{p^p-1}{p-1} = 1+p+p^2+\cdots+p^{p-1},$$but how do we show this is not prime?

Comment: Would be much easier if it were $\frac{p^{p-1}-1}{p-1}$. Or $\frac{p^{p+k}-1}{p-1}$ for any odd $k$, really.

Comment: What have you tried?  I factored the numbers with $p=5,13,17$ and didn't find any factors that were obviously related to $p$

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223847/prove-that-all-divisors-of-fracpp-1p-1-are-of-the-form-pk1-where-p

Comment: @RossMillikan if $f(p) = \frac{p^p - 1}{p - 1}$, then $5\times 2 + 1 \mid f(5)$ and $13 \times 4 + 1 \mid f(13)$ and $17 \times 644 + 1 \mid f(17)$ ... the key seems to be to look at the problem in terms of $\pmod {p + 1}$, and it might help to keep in mind the the sum $\sum_{k = 1}^p p^k \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^p k \pmod{p + 1}$ because modular exponents form a bijection.

Comment: Also $29 \times 2 + 1 \mid f(29)$

Comment: @DanielV $(p^p-1)/(p-1)\equiv 1\pmod p$, so it must have a prime divisor of form $kp+1$, if it's not prime(in fact all divisor of $(p^p-1)/(p-1)$ is of form $kp+1$.

Comment: it is also for first 20 primes :(

Comment: Worth noting that the sum is $\equiv 1 \mod p$ and $\mod p+1$ and $\mod p^3+1$

Comment: and $\mod p^2+1$

Comment: and thus also mod any product of those less than itself.

Comment: @GabrielBurns : why would it be easier for $(p^{p-1}-1)/(p-1)$ ?

Comment: @Alphonse because that would be a summation with $p-1$ terms, all congruent to $1 \mod 4$.  Since $p-1 \equiv 0 \mod 4$, the result would be a multiple of $4$.

Comment: This might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: @user Where do you get this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

We may notice that $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}=\Phi_p(p)$, where $\Phi_p$ is the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial. If we assume that for some prime $q$ we have $\Phi_p(x)\equiv 0\pmod{q}$, then $x$ has order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(q\mathbb{Z})^*$, hence $p\mid(q-1)$, or $q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, by Lagrange's theorem. Additionally, the constraint $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ ensures that $\Phi_p(p)$ has a [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization).

Comment: Does this solve the question?

Comment: @user19405892: I guess so, since a Aurifeuillean factorization ensures that $\Phi_p(p)$ cannot be prime.

Comment: For short, the fact that $p$ splits in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ implies that $\Phi_p(p)$ splits over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Where can I find a reference about proofs of which cyclotomic polynomials have an Aurifeuillean factorization ?

Comment: @misao: what about the linked Wikipedia page?

Comment: In the linked Wiki page only the fact is stated and the documents in the reference, further reading section doesn't seem to contain any proof

Comment: @misao: Aurifeullean factorizations are ultimately a consequence of Gauss sums: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum

Comment: @misao I found [Paul Garrett's notes on Aurifeuillean stuff useful](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/number_theory/aurifeuillian.pdf). Note, Paul Garrett also contributes here occasionally.